# flutter hive_flutter cuando cambio la estructura de la data falla las actualizaciones

Tags: flutter, hive

estoy usando Flutter 3.7.3 • channel stable
y hive_flutter 1.1.0 [https://pub.dev/packages/hive_flutter]

Comienzo con decirles que estoy usando hive y me va espectacular
tengo declarado modelos como voy a mostrar en el ejemplo

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
@HiveType(typeId: 8)
class Product extends Equatable with BaseModel {
  @HiveField(0)
  final int id;
  @HiveField(1)
  final String provcode;
  @HiveField(2)
  final String name;
  @HiveField(3)
  final String descr;
  @HiveField(4)
  final String marca;
  @HiveField(5)
  final int envase;
  @HiveField(6)
  final int bulto;
  @HiveField(7)
  final double? price;
```

ahi todo bien,
pero cuando cambio esa estructura por ejemplo si agrego un campo mas al modelo

@HiveField(8)
final bool? isPopular;

como es normal, reconstruyo la base de datos hive

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

al momento de enviar la actualización a los telefonos que ya tienen la aplicación
falla,

```
E/flutter ( 5925): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast
E/flutter ( 5925): #0      CartPedidosAdapter.read (package:denmob/models/cart_pedidos_model.g.dart:20)
E/flutter ( 5925): #1      BinaryReaderImpl.read (package:hive/src/binary/binary_reader_impl.dart:328)
E/flutter ( 5925): #2      BinaryReaderImpl.readFrame (package:hive/src/binary/binary_reader_impl.dart:276)
E/flutter ( 5925): #3      StorageBackendVm.readValue.<anonymous closure> (package:hive/src/backend/vm/storage_backend_vm.dart:111)
E/flutter ( 5925): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5925): #4      LazyBoxImpl.get (package:hive/src/box/lazy_box_impl.dart:32)
E/flutter ( 5925): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5925): #5      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:522)
E/flutter ( 5925): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5925): #6      CollectionBox.getAllValues (package:hive/src/box_collection/box_collection.dart:159)
E/flutter ( 5925): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5925): #7      LocalStorageRepository.getProducts (package:denmob/repositories/local_storage/local_storage_repository.dart:128)
E/flutter ( 5925): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5925): #8      ProductBloc._onInitialProducts (package:denmob/blocs/product/product_bloc.dart:259)
E/flutter ( 5925): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5925): #9      Bloc.on.<anonymous closure>.handleEvent (package:bloc/src/bloc.dart:226)
E/flutter ( 5925): <asynchronous suspension>
```

esto lo puedo entender porque la base de datos ha cambiado y seguramente los indices no coinciden o algo así.
para que pueda instalar y usar correctamente el usuario tiene que borrar caché y tambien almacenamiento desde el menú de android.
haciendo eso si funciona.

la pregunta es si hay alguna forma de que al hacer la actualización si la app detecta que cambia la estructura de la data pueda hacer borrado de la base de datos?
Necesito evitar que el usuario tenga que intervenir en el proceso de actualización.

desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Tendrías que hacer algunos cambios en tu api quizás, como al inicio de la app, enviarle la versión actual de la app, si el server te retorna que ya tiene una versión nueva, entonces haces el borrado de tu data que tienes en Hive.

Comment: Si buena idea, mas simple de lo que pensaba,
muchas gracias @diegoveloper